# Pass list Ajax(Json) to Controller C# MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I have a view with a form with a lot information like a table and each row is a new item.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzlWy.png)

I do an Ajax to send this list to Controller

This `cont` are the each row of my view.

```js
    function salvarDerivacoes(cont) {
       var arrayItems= [];
       for (var i = 0; i <= cont; i++) {
           arrayItems[i] = {
               ID: parseInt(i),
               Number: $(".number_" + i).text(),
               S1: parseInt($(".s1_" + i).val()),
               S2: parseInt($(".s2_" + i).val()),
               S3: parseInt($(".s3_" + i).val()),
               S4: parseInt($(".s4_" + i).val()),
               S5: parseInt($(".s5_" + i).val()),
               S6: parseInt($(".s6_" + i).val()),
               S7: parseInt($(".s7_" + i).val()),
               S8: parseInt($(".s8_" + i).val()),
               S9: parseInt($(".s9_" + i).val()),
               S10: parseInt($(".s10_" + i).val())
           }
       }
       $.ajax({
          url: "Save",
          type: 'POST',
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          cache: false,
          data: JSON.stringify({ json: arrayItems })
        })
    }
```

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(List<MyObject> json)
{
}
```

But, when I have a many rows (above +/- 30), it never call my Controller, when I have below +/- 15 items, it work.

What is the problem? or How can i do this better?

[Server Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOoSc.png)

Have this 2 to:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   POST http://localhost/Page/Save 500 (Internal Server Error)

[Response Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gcVp.png)

Comment: What is the response you're getting from the server?

Comment: where can i see this?

Comment: you can find response on network tap in developer console

Comment: edited my post with Server Response, is this what you want?

Comment: click on the response and select Preview to get details of `internal server error`

Comment: but, like i sad before, works when i have few items

Comment: Thanks you both, i didnt know how to see this..

Comment: you are welcome ,check this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/32433206/6522459
may it help you

Comment: that worked, thank you so much

Comment: What do I need to do to 'close' (like solved) this post?